# JS Find match in an array of objects and if its value is 0 remove it otherwise move it to the end of the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dataset:

```
 var labels = ["Caterer", "INDEED", "Sarova Website", "Send to Friend", "alexandre-creed.com", "amdas.co.uk", "catabaseuk.co.uk", "cerecruit.co.uk", "el8recruitment.com", "equinoxresourcing.co.uk", "gatewayjobs.co.uk", "hotelstaffpec.co.uk", "jwrecruitment.co.uk", "marshallhr.co.uk", "marshallhr.com (Sarova)", "momentumrecruitment.com", "peoplebank.com", "ph-recruitment.co.uk", "platinum-hospitality.co.uk", "q", "talenthive.co.uk", "towngate-personnel.co.uk"];

var dataSet = {
  "ADVERTS_PUBLISHED": ["102", "130", "153", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "3", "8", "4", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", "1", "2"],
  "VIEWS": ["1642", "10566", "45269", "7", "4", "1", "11", "9", "11", "12", "5", "0", "14", "6", "3", "13", "19", "2", "8", "3", "2", "2"],
  "CLICKS": ["1992", "3628", "4458", "4", "2", "2", "7", "3", "11", "5", "6", "9", "10", "15", "10", "4", "34", "10", "10", "3", "0", "8"],
  "SUBMITTED": ["1101", "877", "1290", "2", "3", "2", "10", "14", "11", "5", "5", "7", "6", "14", "8", "6", "17", "7", "9", "4", "1", "6"],
  "PENDING": ["115", "26", "93", "0", "1", "0", "7", "3", "6", "2", "0", "0", "4", "8", "0", "3", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
  "FILTERED": ["546", "493", "764", "1", "2", "2", "9", "12", "10", "5", "4", "5", "5", "12", "2", "3", "4", "6", "4", "0", "1", "5"],
  "SHORTLISTED": ["37", "23", "32", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "1"],
  "REGRETTED": ["103", "28", "52", "0", "1", "0", "1", "6", "5", "3", "0", "2", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "3", "1", "0", "0", "2"],
  "INTERVIEWED": ["62", "45", "88", "0", "0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "2", "0", "3", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
  "OFFERED": ["4", "10", "20", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  "OFFERED_AND_DECLINED": ["0", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  "REGRETTED_AND_COMM": ["587", "334", "533", "0", "0", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0", "1", "2", "4", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0"],
  "ACTUAL_HIRED": ["4", "2", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
};
```

The following code computes an array named slices, that holds objects with properties label and value for all slices to be included in the chart. All values below 1 percent are summed and held by the object labeled "Others".

How would i go about making the "Others" always the last element in the slices array and remove it altogether if the Others value is 0?

```
 //create dataset that includes the others grouping
    dataSet2 = [];
    Object.keys(dataSet).forEach(function (item) {
        dataSet2[item] = groupOthers(dataSet[item], 1);
    });

    //groups data points together
    function groupOthers(dataSet, thresholdPercent = 10) {
        const values = dataSet.map(v => Number(v));
        const valueSum = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        const slices = values.map((v, i) => ({ label: labels[i], value: v }))
    .reduce((accumulator, currObj) => {
            const percent = 100 * currObj.value / valueSum;
        if (percent < thresholdPercent) {
            const others = accumulator.find(o => o.label == 'Others');
            if (!others) {
                return accumulator.concat({ label: 'Others', value: currObj.value });
            }
            others.value += currObj.value;
        } else {
            accumulator.push(currObj);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, []);

        return slices;
    }
```

I have tried altering the code like so but I am by no means a JS expert:

```
//find Others object in array and move it to the last element if it exists
     obj =  slices.find(o => o.label === 'Others');

     if(obj !== null){
         //move others to last element of array
         slices.push(slices.shift());

         //get last element of array
         var last_element = slices[slices.length - 1];


         if(last_element.label == 'Others'){

             //if value of others is 0 remove last element from array
             if(last_element.value == 0){
                 slices.splice(-1,1)
             }
         }
     }

     return slices;
```

Output would be something like the following

```
0: {label: "whatever", value: 4}
1: {label: "...", value: 2}
2: {label: "....", value: 1}
3: {label: "....", value: 1}
4: {label: "....", value: 2}
5: {label: "....", value: 1}
6: {label: "....", value: 1}
7: {label: "....", value: 1}
8: {label: "....", value: 1}
9: {label: "Others", value: 2}
```

Comment: can you share expected output?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Is that the output for just one of the keys in dataSet? Or where did those keys go?

Comment: yeah just the output for one of the keys

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to switch first to array format, do the mapping and filtering, and use the opposite `Object.fromEntries` to get back the object representation:

```js
var labels = ["Caterer", "INDEED", "Sarova Website", "Send to Friend", "alexandre-creed.com", "amdas.co.uk", "catabaseuk.co.uk", "cerecruit.co.uk", "el8recruitment.com", "equinoxresourcing.co.uk", "gatewayjobs.co.uk", "hotelstaffpec.co.uk", "jwrecruitment.co.uk", "marshallhr.co.uk", "marshallhr.com (Sarova)", "momentumrecruitment.com", "peoplebank.com", "ph-recruitment.co.uk", "platinum-hospitality.co.uk", "q", "talenthive.co.uk", "towngate-personnel.co.uk"];

var dataSet = {"ADVERTS_PUBLISHED": ["102", "130", "153", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "3", "8", "4", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", "1", "2"],"VIEWS": ["1642", "10566", "45269", "7", "4", "1", "11", "9", "11", "12", "5", "0", "14", "6", "3", "13", "19", "2", "8", "3", "2", "2"],"CLICKS": ["1992", "3628", "4458", "4", "2", "2", "7", "3", "11", "5", "6", "9", "10", "15", "10", "4", "34", "10", "10", "3", "0", "8"],"SUBMITTED": ["1101", "877", "1290", "2", "3", "2", "10", "14", "11", "5", "5", "7", "6", "14", "8", "6", "17", "7", "9", "4", "1", "6"],"PENDING": ["115", "26", "93", "0", "1", "0", "7", "3", "6", "2", "0", "0", "4", "8", "0", "3", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],"FILTERED": ["546", "493", "764", "1", "2", "2", "9", "12", "10", "5", "4", "5", "5", "12", "2", "3", "4", "6", "4", "0", "1", "5"],"SHORTLISTED": ["37", "23", "32", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "1"],"REGRETTED": ["103", "28", "52", "0", "1", "0", "1", "6", "5", "3", "0", "2", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "3", "1", "0", "0", "2"],"INTERVIEWED": ["62", "45", "88", "0", "0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "2", "0", "3", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "1"],"OFFERED": ["4", "10", "20", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],"OFFERED_AND_DECLINED": ["0", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],"REGRETTED_AND_COMM": ["587", "334", "533", "0", "0", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0", "1", "2", "4", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0"],"ACTUAL_HIRED": ["4", "2", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]};

var threshold = 10;

var res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(dataSet).map(([metric, values]) =>
  [metric, values
    .filter(v => +v > threshold)
    .map((v, i) => ({label: labels[i], value: +v}))
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
    .concat({
      label: "others",
      value: values.reduce((acc, v) => acc + (+v <= threshold && +v), 0)
    })
  ]
));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script just a tiny bit for it to return the result you want:

Before returning `slices` the array is sorted using a special compare function:

```
function(a,b){
  return (a.label=='Others'?1:0)-(b.label=='Others'?1:0);
}
```

This function will keep the order of all elements but the ones with `label=="Others"` unchanged.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var labels = ["Caterer", "INDEED", "Sarova Website", "Send to Friend", "alexandre-creed.com", "amdas.co.uk", "catabaseuk.co.uk", "cerecruit.co.uk", "el8recruitment.com", "equinoxresourcing.co.uk", "gatewayjobs.co.uk", "hotelstaffpec.co.uk", "jwrecruitment.co.uk", "marshallhr.co.uk", "marshallhr.com (Sarova)", "momentumrecruitment.com", "peoplebank.com", "ph-recruitment.co.uk", "platinum-hospitality.co.uk", "q", "talenthive.co.uk", "towngate-personnel.co.uk"];
var dataSet = {
  "ADVERTS_PUBLISHED": ["102", "130", "153", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "3", "8", "4", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", "1", "2"],
  "VIEWS": ["1642", "10566", "45269", "7", "4", "1", "11", "9", "11", "12", "5", "0", "14", "6", "3", "13", "19", "2", "8", "3", "2", "2"],
  "CLICKS": ["1992", "3628", "4458", "4", "2", "2", "7", "3", "11", "5", "6", "9", "10", "15", "10", "4", "34", "10", "10", "3", "0", "8"],
  "SUBMITTED": ["1101", "877", "1290", "2", "3", "2", "10", "14", "11", "5", "5", "7", "6", "14", "8", "6", "17", "7", "9", "4", "1", "6"],
  "PENDING": ["115", "26", "93", "0", "1", "0", "7", "3", "6", "2", "0", "0", "4", "8", "0", "3", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
  "FILTERED": ["546", "493", "764", "1", "2", "2", "9", "12", "10", "5", "4", "5", "5", "12", "2", "3", "4", "6", "4", "0", "1", "5"],
  "SHORTLISTED": ["37", "23", "32", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "1"],
  "REGRETTED": ["103", "28", "52", "0", "1", "0", "1", "6", "5", "3", "0", "2", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "3", "1", "0", "0", "2"],
  "INTERVIEWED": ["62", "45", "88", "0", "0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "2", "0", "3", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
  "OFFERED": ["4", "10", "20", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  "OFFERED_AND_DECLINED": ["0", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  "REGRETTED_AND_COMM": ["587", "334", "533", "0", "0", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0", "1", "2", "4", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0"],
  "ACTUAL_HIRED": ["4", "2", "8", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
};

//create dataset that includes the others grouping
var res = Object.keys(dataSet).reduce(function(ds,item) {
      ds[item] = groupOthers(dataSet[item],1); return ds;
      }, {} );
console.log(res);

//groups data points together
function groupOthers(dataSet, thresholdPercent = 10) {
  const values = dataSet.map(v => Number(v));
  const valueSum = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  const slices = values.map((v, i) => ({ label: labels[i], value: v }))
   .reduce((accumulator, currObj) => {
        const percent = 100 * currObj.value / valueSum;
        if (percent < thresholdPercent) {
            const others = accumulator.find(o => o.label == 'Others');
            if (!others) {
                return accumulator.concat({ label: 'Others', value: currObj.value });
            }
            others.value += currObj.value;
        } else {
            accumulator.push(currObj);
        }
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
  // ====== ONLY CHANGE HAPPENS HERE ============= START ===
  // slices are sorted, so "Others" will always come last:
  return slices.sort(function(a,b){
     return (a.label=='Others'?1:0)-(b.label=='Others'?1:0);
  });
  // ====== ONLY CHANGE HAPPENS HERE =============== END ===
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

I have to concede, that @trincot's approach is to be preferred. His code solves the whole issue in a more direct way and makes my "sorting business" superfluous. Still, my code can be seen as a "polyfill" to make your originally supplied code work.